Creating a vineyard map with QGIS
I'm trying to plot dots (the vines) in an irregularly shaped polygon. they are in parallel rows spaced 1.4 m apart and the vines are spaced 1.2 m apart. The rows are at a 45º angle from N. I tried to create a fishnet and then line intersection, but I can't figure out how to rotate it and fit it within the polygon. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Have you tried via:
Vector -> Research Tools -> Create Grid

Fill your Parameters: Points with 1.4m and 1.2m spacing
Then select all your created points on the map and use the rotate tool, rotate by 45°. Optionally, select thenn all points within your vineyard polygon, reveret selection and delete this selection (should now be the points outside your polygon).

So I created a grid and inputted 1.4 m and 1.2m but then the lines are actually only 1 m and 0.8 m apart when I measure it and I cant' figure out why.

@SophieBernstein what coordinate system are you using? The units of create grid are those of your coordinate system

@BERA I'm using WGS-84
